# Styling a map with CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, image-editing

I have a CSS map of Brazil that I want to make have yellow borders:
[image]

Can you inform me how I make the borders yellow so my map looks more similar to this:
[image]

I also want to know how to make the black background larger since the map is larger than the background. The relevant HTML and CSS is:

```
    <div class="main_container" style="padding-top: 15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; height: 450px;width: 912px;"><form name="cse" action="/buscar" id="cse-search-box">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="cx" value="partner-pub-7211665888260307:9230854672" />
<input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:10" />
<input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
<input type="text" name="q" size="55" />
<input type="submit" name="sa" value="Buscar" />
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com.br/coop/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&amp;lang=pt"></script>
    <div class="map_left map map_container" style="margin-top: -11px;">
        <div id="area_image" class="map sprite-map_new sprite-background">
            <div class="" id="area_highlight" style="z-index: 0;position:absolute;"></div><img style="z-index: 999; position: absolute;" src="/static/montaonegocio_files/transparent.gif" alt="" usemap="#indexmap" width="500" height="480">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="site-description" style="height: 220px;">
        <h1 style="padding-top: 10px;"><a href="/">Anúncios</a> no site Montao.com.br:</h1>
        <h2>são colocados manualmente pelo usuário aqui.</h2>

    </div>

    <div id="info_tips" style="padding-top: 0px; height: 215px; margin-top: -5px;">
        <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 18px;">Todos os anúncios são revistos pela equipe do Montao.com.br</h3>
        <ul style="margin-top: 13px;">
            <li><img src="/static/montaonegocio_files/transparent.gif" class="sprite-square_1 sprite-background">O anúncio será visível durante dois messes. </li>
            <li><img src="/static/montaonegocio_files/transparent.gif" class="sprite-square_2 sprite-background"><strong class="OrangeText">Grátis!</strong> </li>
            <li><img src="/static/montaonegocio_files/transparent.gif" class="sprite-square_3 sprite-background"></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <a class="logo " style="text-decoration: none;" href="/.htm?ca=11_s"><img class="sprite-logo_new sprite-background" alt="Montao.com.br" src="/static/montaonegocio_files/transparent.gif" border="0"></a>
    </div>




body {
    font-family:  'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'Liberation Sans', FreeSans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0px;
    color:#2C4F66;
    background-color:#000000;
    line-height:1.3;
}

div#footer {
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 5px 0 0 15px;
    width: 940px;
}
#footer a:link,
#footer a:hover,
#footer a:visited { color: #999 }
#footer .footer_item {
    display: inline;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #999;
}
#footer .footer_right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: right;
}
#footer .footer_left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: left;
}
a:hover { text-decoration: none }
.Container {
    width: 960px;
    position: relative;
    background-color:#ffffef;
    margin: 5px 0 0 20px;
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
}
.IndexContainer { padding: 5px 0 0 10px }
.BannerShadow { margin: 0 }
.map {
    width: 500px;
    height: 480px;
}
.map_container {
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    margin: 7px 0;
}
.show_state_name {
    left: 780px;
    width: 125px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    background: #d4d4d4;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.AreaList {
    background: #fff7db;
    border: 1px solid #e5dec5;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 18px 0;
}
.expl_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    display: block;
}
.Explanation {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 1.65em;
    margin: 0 0 0 713px;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
.main_container {
    width: 903px;
    height: 472px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 25px 10px 25px 25px;
    background: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
#site-description h1,
#site-description h2,
#site-description h3 {
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #666;
    margin: 0;
}
#site-description h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    color: #000;
}
#site-description h2 { font-size: 2.2em }
#site-description h3 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    margin: 1.6em 0 0 0;
}
#info_tips,
#site-description {
    width: 300px;
    height: 216px;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    background: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 5px 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.small_txt {
    font-size: .8em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#info_tips h3 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}
#info_tips ul {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    _margin-top: 40px;
}
#info_tips li {
    line-height: 2.2em;
    _height: 2.2em;
}
#info_tips img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 26px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.index_regions span {
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    color: #999;
}
.index_regions .regions_links {
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: right;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.index_regions a {
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#header-line {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 12px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 710px;
    height: 2px;
}
#header-payoff {
    clear: right;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #e00c16;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#AdRight {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 200px;
}
#AdRight img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.handheld_tip { display: none }
#AdRight .right-campaign {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#News {
    font-size: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#News a { font-size: 12px }
#News .pipe {
    color: #999;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
.news_large { width: 930px }
* html .news_large { width: 941px }
*+html .news_large { width: 935px }
.news_small { width: 728px }
#startpage_ie {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 88px 0 0 326px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 40000;
}
#startpage_ff {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 88px 0 0 326px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 40000;
    line-height: 110%;
}
#startpage_ff_info #ff2_fix {
    position: absolute;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
#startpage_ff_info {
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent url(/img/startpage_ff.png) no-repeat;
    width: 232px;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 315px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 40001;
}
#startpage_ff_info .logo { padding: 30px 0 0 0 }
#startpage_ff_info .icon {
    border: 2px dashed #b5af83;
    margin-right: 7px;
}
#startpage_ff_info .infotext {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 7px 20px 0 20px;
}
#startpage_ff_info .logo img { padding: 5px }
#startpage_ff_info .close {
    text-align: right;
    margin: 12px 20px 0 0;
}
#startpage_sf {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 20px 0 0 315px;
    text-align: center;
}
.StateList td {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 16px;
}
.StateList a:visited { color: #936 }
#AdTop {
    margin-top: 4px;
    height: 90px;
}
#AdSquare td {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: center;
}
#AdSquare .LeftCol,
#AdSquare .RightCol { padding: 5px 0 0 0 }
#AdSquare .LeftCol {
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 150px;
}
#AdSquare .RightCol { padding-right: 12px }
#AdSquare {
    width: 283px;
    margin: 8px 0 0 12px;
}
#AdSquare .Ad .Empty { margin: 0 }
#AdSquare .Jobb24 { margin: 0 0 12px 0 }
#AdSquare .Jobb24Text { padding-bottom: 1px }
#AdSquare .MatchLink {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#AdSquare .Sesam {
    margin: 1px 0 0 13px;
    padding: 0;
}
#AdSquare .Sesam form {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#AdSquare .AdBottom { margin: 10px 0 0 0 }
#AdSquare .AdBottom {
    height: 120px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: verdana;
    padding: 12px 0 0 12px;
    margin: 0;
}
#AdSquare .AdBottom {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 12px;
}
#AdSquare .AdBottom .Text {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 230px;
    line-height: 105%;
    margin: 0 0 0 12px;
}
#AdSquare .AdBottom .TextBoxWho {
    width: 140px;
    font-family: verdana,arial,helvetica;
    font-size: 11px;
}
#AdSquare .AdBottom .TextBoxWhere {
    width: 140px;
    font-family: verdana,arial,helvetica;
    font-size: 11px;
}
#AdSquare .MatchText {
    margin: 9px 0 -4px 0;
    position: relative;
}
.clean_table,
.clean_table td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.shadowed_thumb .middle_left {
    background: url(/img/thumb_border_left.gif) repeat-y;
    width: 2px;
}
.shadowed_thumb .top_middle {
    background: url(/img/thumb_border_top.gif) repeat-x;
    height: 2px;
}
.shadowed_thumb .extra_middle_right {
    background: url(/img/thumb_extra_border_right.gif) repeat-y;
    width: 6px;
}
.shadowed_thumb .extra_bottom_center {
    background: url(/img/thumb_extra_border_bottom.gif) repeat-x;
    height: 6px;
}
.shadowed_thumb .single_middle_right {
    background: url(/img/thumb_single_border_right.gif) repeat-y;
    width: 6px;
}
.shadowed_thumb .single_bottom_center {
    background: url(/img/thumb_single_border_bottom.gif) repeat-x;
    height: 6px;
}
.Front {
    margin: 9px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
.RedText { color: #c00 }
.OrangeText { color: #fe7b07 }
.AdsNow { margin: 14px 0 0 0 }
.sprite-background { background: url(http://www.montao.com.br/_/img/montao_sprites.gif) no-repeat scroll transparent }
.sprite-balcao_logo_new {
    background-position: -50px -265px;
    width: 133px;
    height: 48px;
}
.sprite-insert_ad {
    background-position: -13px -145px;
    width: 227px;
    height: 38px;
}
.sprite-logo_new {
    background-position: -11px -25px;
    width: 421px;
    height: 81px;
}
.sprite-map_new {
    background-position: -465px 0;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-orange_arrow {
    background-position: -65px -213px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 13px;
}
.sprite-state_1 {
    background-position: -7572px -2px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_10 {
    background-position: -3597px -165px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_11 {
    background-position: -5483px -2px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_12 {
    background-position: -4298px -3px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 369px;
}
.sprite-state_13 {
    background-position: -3390px -1px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 268px;
}
.sprite-state_14 {
    background-position: -5080px -2px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_15 {
    background-position: -3389px -259px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_16 {
    background-position: -2934px -1px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 320px;
}
.sprite-state_17 {
    background-position: -2934px -259px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_18 {
    background-position: -2346px -283px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_19 {
    background-position: -2659px -1px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 369px;
}
.sprite-state_2 {
    background-position: -7176px -3px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_20 {
    background-position: -2344px -2px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 369px;
}
.sprite-state_21 {
    background-position: -2077px -2px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_22 {
    background-position: -1637px -2px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_23 {
    background-position: -1102px -174px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_24 {
    background-position: -1306px -71px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_25 {
    background-position: -1015px -251px;
    width: 157px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_26 {
    background-position: 83px -380px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_27 {
    background-position: -989px -1px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 169px;
}
.sprite-state_3 {
    background-position: -6791px -2px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_4 {
    background-position: -6364px -2px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_5 {
    background-position: -6082px -1px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_6 {
    background-position: -5781px -3px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_7 {
    background-position: -4623px -2px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_8 {
    background-position: -3971px -311px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 469px;
}
.sprite-state_9 {
    background-position: -3972px -2px;
    width: 457px;
    height: 269px;
}
.sprite-square_1 {
    background-position: -296px -150px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 26px;
}
.sprite-square_2 {
    background-position: -332px -150px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 26px;
}
.sprite-square_3 {
    background-position: -366px -150px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 26px;
}
html { height: 100% }
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#TableContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#Page {
    width: 960px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 6px 0 0 40px;
}
td,
tr,
table {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul,
ol { margin-top: 0 }
a {
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #144678;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
}
a:hover { text-decoration: underline }
```

Comment: There is way too much code here.

Comment: The border is part of the image and not something you can change with css.

Comment: Use scaled vector graphics? http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of the image is found here according to your page:
http://www.montao.com.br/_/img/montao_sprites.gif

Unless there is something I'm missing, If you download that file you should be able to use Photoshop or something to add yellow borders manually.